# A localization of a topos is still a topos

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to see how a localization of a topos is a topos. That is, localization of a cartesian closed category is cartesian closed, and if a category has a subobject classifier any localization of it has it too. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "localisation"? What is true is this: if $\mathcal{E}$ is a topos and $\mathcal{E}'$ is a full subcategory of $\mathcal{E}$ such that the inclusion $\mathcal{E}' \hookrightarrow \mathcal{E}$ has a left adjoint that preserves finite limits, then $\mathcal{E}'$ is also a topos. It is relatively straightforward to show that $\mathcal{E}'$ is cartesian closed – the hard part is constructing the subobject classifier.

Comment: @ZhenLin "full subcategory of E such that the inclusion has a left adjoint that preserves finite limits" is the definition of localization that I had in mind.

Comment: Right. Well, as I said, it's not an easy result. Look up universal closure operators, e.g. [_Sheaves in geometry and logic_, Ch. V §1] or [_Sketches of an elephant_, Part A, §4.3].